# Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph. What is a mutual neighbor of a set $R$ where $R \subset V(G)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, random-graphs

> Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph with $V$ set of vertices, $E$ edges. What is the set of mutual neigbors of a set $R \subset V(G)$? In particular, what is a mutual neighbor of a set $R \subset V(G)$?

This notation is at the end of page 2 of the following paper and I could not find any definition on the Internet:
https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/eth-its/Documents/lecture5.pdf

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just based on experience, I would guess the mutual neighbors of $R$ are the vertices adjacent to all the vertices of $R$.

Some evidence to back it up ([google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=-GjyKFSPIksC&pg=PA259&lpg=PA259&dq=%22mutual%20neighbors%22%20graph&source=bl&ots=WIrTKWdEMQ&sig=C3_7u3Yt1gzaUXXVs6MT8SHlU7c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt5c-Xlo3QAhVoh1QKHR5tB5sQ6AEIMTAF#v=onepage&q=%22mutual%20neighbors%22%20graph&f=false)).

Comment: Could it be adjacent to 2 vertices in $R$? Since "mutual" is notation for a pair.

Comment: I would submit that "mutual" can refer to more than two, while you're thinking of "pairwise."

Comment: Don't know how to edit a comment...  For example: 6, 12, 22, and 27 are "mutually relatively prime" but not "pairwise relatively prime"

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope you're right :)